# Correct mouse event order on a doubleclick

Tags: c++, user-interface

What's the correct order of events I should see when a user does a double click?

- Down - Up - Down - DoubleClick - Up
- Down - Up - DoubleClick - Down - Up
- Down - Up - DoubleClick - Up

Is this be platform specific? How should it work in Windows?

Comment: Why not create a simple application that listens to all mousebutton events, and you find out by yourself?

Comment: I did one, but now we are arguing if it's correct or do we need to change it for our framework. I would just like to know if there is a silver bullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows API - variant 3:

Only windows that have the CS_DBLCLKS style can receive WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK messages, which the system generates whenever the user presses, releases, and again presses the left mouse button within the system's double-click time limit. Double-clicking the left mouse button actually generates a sequence of four messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606(v=vs.85).aspx